# Move windows between KDE activties

Tags: kde, virtual-desktop, window-manager, kwin, kde-plasma-workspace

KDE 4.6 Plasma Workspaces added support for managing windows in [Activities](http://hanschen.org/2011/02/04/activities-a-change-in-workflow/), which are a sort of combination between virtual desktops and session management. But I still haven't figured out some basic functionality, and `khelpcenter` doesn't seem to document the new Activities feature.

Particularly, how do you move a window to another KDE activity (i.e. using a keyboard shortcut)?

Comment: I don't like those activities at all, but I think they are just collections of widgets, and virtual desktops are still responsible for window management.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: In recent versions they added window-management features to activities.

Comment: I tried to use these activities as a replacement for the Desktops, as I liked to the feature pin an application shortcut in the task bar to only one activity. What a pity these activities are stuck in the same state as when I first tried to use them, about 7 years ago.

Answer (score 9):

If you click on the window top-left icon you will open the window menu; from there, if you have more than one activity opened, you will see a submenu entry that will let you select in which activities you want to see the current application window.
Please note that any window can be shown in multiple activities at the same time, so, if you want to move it, i.e., from the "activity 1" to "activity 2", you have to check, in the said submenu, "activity 2" and uncheck "activity 1".

As far as I know, there aren't keyboard shortcuts, which is a true pity.

Answer (score 3):

you can access the " operational menu " of the window ( the menu that unfolds when you click the icon in the upper left icon ) pressing alt+f3. then navigate the menu with arrows.

Comment: With two actions, Alt-F3 (editable) and then A-key, you get that list.  It gets a bit odd after that if you have just 2 activities (I guess you are supposed to have more than 2 and have one application on more than one activity): if you have just 2 activities, an application cannot be send directly from activity A to activity B. It has to be sent on all activities first  (any click will trigger that), and then click the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create hotkeys for this that change the '_KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES' X-window property.

```
xprop -f _KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES 8s -id $(xdotool getwindowfocus) -set _KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES $YOUR-ACTIVITY-ID-CSV-LIST
```

I posted a script that creates a toggle feature and manages duplicates, etc. here:
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=174102

Answer (score 0):

Adding to kde-jon3's answer, I map these to keyboard shortcuts (my activities are named after the letters on my keyboard).

It's not pretty but it works.

```
xprop \
-f _KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES 8s \
-id $(xdotool getwindowfocus) \
-set _KDE_NET_WM_ACTIVITIES \
$(dbus-send --session --dest=org.kde.ActivityManager \
  --type=method_call \
  --print-reply=literal \
  /ActivityManager/Activities \
  "org.kde.ActivityManager.Activities.ListActivitiesWithInformation" | 
 \
  grep <The name of your destination activity> | \
  awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }'\
)
```